# Annoying bootstrap horizontal alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form and I want to keep 2 or 3 controls in line in the same row, for example:

```
label1

r1_ctrl1 r1_ctrl2 r1_ctrl3

label2 

r2_ctrl1 r2_ctrl2 r2_ctrl3
```

I tried to do it this way:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
<label...>
<div class="form-group">
<select .../>
<a ... />
</div>
</form>
```

and it does not work.
I also tried:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
<label...>
<div class="form-group"> 
<div class="controls form-inline"
<select .../>
<a ... />
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

And also no result.
The only working method is Html table, but the result is really ugly. Please advise.

Comment: can you show us a demo (like a jsfiddle) that demonstrates the trouble you're running into?

Comment: Aren't you looking for an inline form? http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline

Comment: Show your HTML without the truncations and formatted, please. Apparently you're missing a crucial point in the Bootstrap examples, and it's difficult to see what that might be with half your markup missing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want controls on the same row you shouldn't use:
`.form-horizontal`
but
`.form-inline`

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline

This is what `.form-horizontal` does:

> Individual form controls automatically receive some global styling. All textual , , and  elements with .form-control are set to width: 100%; by default. Wrap labels and controls in .form-group for optimum spacing.

[image]

And this is what `.form-inline` does:

> Add .form-inline to your  for left-aligned and inline-block controls. This only applies to forms within viewports that are at least 768px wide.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would take advantage of Bootstrap's flexible grid layout:

```
<div class="row">
    <form>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <h3>Heading 1</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 form-group">
            <label for="input1">
                <input id="input1" class="form-control" value="Control 1"></input>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 form-group">
            <label for="input2">
                <input id="input2" class="form-control" value="Control 2"></input>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 form-group">
            <label for="input3">
                <input id="input3" class="form-control" value="Control 3"></input>
            </label>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/8q364gk1/)

Notice that I've changed your label to a heading. Each input should have its own label (with an appropriate `for` attribute) for accessibility. In this demo, the `for` attributes aren't strictly necessary as the labels wrap the inputs.